# jQuery Validate stop form submit with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

So,

I have been using jQuery Validate for from validation and I have stumbled across something that puzzling me.

I have the form validating properly which is working right but this form is in a modal. Now big deal but when I hit submit, it activates an ajax post, the modal goes away and a DIV on the page updates.

What happens is: The validation works but the ajax still posts.

First: Here is the Javascript validation:

```
<script>


$(function() {

  $.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      if (element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
  });






  $("#testForm").validate({
    rules: {
      contractNumber: {
        required: true
      },

      dateFrom: {
        required: true,
        nowhitespace: true
      },

      dateTo: {
        required: true,
        nowhitespace: true
      },

      contractType: {
        required: true
      }
    },

    messages: {
      contractNumber: {
        required: 'Please enter a contract number.'
    }
}
  });

});

</script>




<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testForm").submit(sendForm)
    });

    function sendForm() {
    $.post('index.cfm/candidate/putContract',$("#testForm").serialize(),function(data,status)
    {   
        $('#addContract').modal('hide');
        $("#contractView").html(data)
        });
    return false
    }
</script>
```

This script hides the modal, then posts the results.

What I would like to happen is the validation happen and only pushing when the validation is passed.

http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/bh6t2h78/

Here is a fiddle that was setup. It does not post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your submit event you can check if the form is valid. try this `$('form').on('submit', function(e){ if(form.valid() == false){ e.preventDefault()} });`

Comment: That works. I do see this in the console 

Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined

Should from be named the name of the form?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Comment: It's working properly with that message in the console. So, besides that it's working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The validation works but the ajax still posts.

That's because your `submit` event handler is bypassing the plugin.  You will not need to capture the `submit` event as that is handled automatically by the plugin.
[As per the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), the `ajax` belongs *inside* of the plugin's `submitHandler` option.

> Replaces the default submit. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    // ajax goes here
    $.post(....);
    return false;
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/bh6t2h78/2/**

In order to get your jsFiddle working properly, I had to comment out your `nowhitespace` rule declarations since this method is presently `undefined`.